# How can I add image map on drupal?

Tags: media, files, uri

I am working on a website that is about history and there are some map for this website.

I am using map tag of HTML to select a part of image(map), how can I merge that `<map>` to `<img>` that uploaded by drupe

or how can I put the image address and merge map to it:

```
<img src="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/geo/sites/default/files/field/image/aa.jpg"  alt="" width="800" height="531" usemap="#Map"/>
<map name="Map">
  <area shape="poly" coords="396,270,516,286,549,324,502,353,447,342,406,343,384,366,400,396,386,414,353,344,346,293,345,263,389,235,428,223,470,234,487,252,596,243" href="#">
</map>
```

**Where is the path (address)  of files on drupal that I can link to it insted of the path that I give on top source** `<img src=" I Mean here"/>`

Comment: you should not give path like that in src.

Comment: I don't know the path of files in drupal

Comment: I give this path but does not working : ` sites/default/files/field/image/aa.jpg`

Comment: add slash (/) to your path. if you sites lives at something/my-drupal-site then path would be /my-drupal-site/sites/all/themes/zen/zen/image.png

Comment: @KrishnaMohan The image is working and showing, but map does not working

Comment: Ok, if you install contributed module that I think would be easy for you. Is that ok?

Comment: what should I do now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15327/discussion-between-kermani-and-krishna-mohan).

Comment: /sites/default/files translates to public://, so you might try using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [jQuery Map Hilight](https://www.drupal.org/project/jq_maphilight) module

> It enables the simple addition of mouseover highlighting of hotspots to HTML image maps without requiring the editing of theme files or knowledge of javascript/jquery.

**Features**

1. provides simple interactive graphics via HTML image maps (no flash
   required).
2. easy to use: either select the 'highlight all image maps' default
   setting or simply add class="jq_maphilight" to the  tag of any
   specific image map you wish to highlight.
3. no jquery or javascript knowledge required: plugin configuration is
   handled via an admin/settings screen rather than having to enter
   jquery code.
4. fully configurable: options for fill, fill color, fill opacity,
   outline, outline color, outline opacity, outline thickness, as well
   as a fade effect.
5. per image map settings: add image map specific options with an
   additional class.

Comment: where do I add this map tag?? I have added an image as a banner in `Marinelli` theme and I wanted to add usemap to it. So where do I write the code for `map tag`

Comment: please look into this post http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/151421/where-do-i-add-imagemap-in-drupal-7