# Where do I add imagemap in drupal 7

Tags: theming, media

I'm using [`marinelli`](https://www.drupal.org/project/marinelli) theme and the rotating images. Now, I'm looking to add `usemap` to some of the images, as the images are rotating images and are not within a specific node. Moreover, I'm adding the banners through `admin->apperance->settings->marinelli->banner management`. So, I couldn't add the `usemap` html tag within the body or some-other place as within blocks/nodes. I tried various ways to add but couldn't get any idea.

I have found some module [`jQuery Map Hilight`](https://www.drupal.org/project/jq_maphilight), where i can add features to the usemap not really adding `usemap` to an image.

Is there any way to add `usemap` tag? Is there any way like adding some code in `page.tpl.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As none of my attempts were working, I tried a completely new approach using views.

I've created a new content type named 'banner'. And in the body field, I've added an html `img tag` and `map tag`(for image mapping). Now, I've created a `view` with format as `slideshow` and field as `content:body`. Creating a `block` for this view and adding it in the advertise region (in marinelli theme) replaces the rotating banner image in `Marinelli` theme.

Before adding the view in advertise region, we need to disable the original theme banner. For this, goto `admin->appearence->settings->marinelli->Banner configuration` and choose 'Drupal region (advertise) for the question `Do you want to use marinelli banners or a classic drupal region?`

Answer (score 1):

There is if you're willing to break apart some theme code. You'll need to stitch together a few changes to make this happen.

1. Map Generation.

You're going to need some front-end tool to select your geometry and map it to hyperlinks. It sounds like plugin/module you found may do this. Failing that, it's pretty easy to find existing online tools to do this: [Example #1](http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/), [Example #2](https://www.image-maps.com/), [Example #3](http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap). It should generate some `map` & `area` elements for you.

2. Storing Maps

Here you're going to be altering the form array/submission-handler in **theme-settings.php** & **template.php** so you can store the maps for each image. There are few parts of this to change:

- `_marinelli_banner_form($image_data)`: This generates the subform that contains all the image form elements. For simplicity, you can add a textfield form element called `image_map` that will contain the map/area markup for each image.
- `marinelli_settings_submit($form, &$form_state)`: This submission handler will need to be altered so you can store the map/area data. A likely area would be the 1st foreach block where you can take each `image_map` and store it into the `$settings` array.

This should be it here. The get/set functions `marinelli_get_banners`/`marinelli_set_banners` are creating a complex array that gets stored into `theme_marinelli_banner_settings` so no additional data structure altercation should be needed. All you need to do is add the image_map element for each stored image.

3. Displaying Maps

Here we're looking at **logics/banners.inc** to alter the rendering. This PHP include contains the banner element markup in the **template.php**:`marinelli_preprocess_page(&vars)` > **page.tpl.php**:`$banner_image` rendering pipeline.

- `marinelli_banner_markup($banners)`: Here each `$banner` should have an array element `image_map` that we defined before. It's using [theme_image](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7) to generate the image. It should be pretty easy to add the `usemap` element, and output the `map/area` markup we've stored. There is also some logic for wrapping the image in a link that needs to be scrubbed out.
- `marinelli_banners_add_js($num_banners)`: This function adds all the JS sources/settings to fire up the slideshow. It may need to be tweaked to make sure the maps cycle correctly when the changing images.

Comment: This didn't work..